# vector of structs with weird behavior c++

Tags: c++, vector, struct, stream

i have a problem with one assignment that i have. I have to read a .ts file, read the packets that are inside and extract header information from each packet.
I have created a struct Packet that will hold all the info of the header, and i also have a vector in which i will push_back each Packet.
The problem is that the for loop stops for some reason on the 163rd loop. If i loop until lets say i=160, then the code escapes ends the loop, but when i print the vector.size() i get a really huge number which doesn't make sense. i guess it should be an integer value as high as the pushed back number of Packets.Here is the code that i have so far:

```
int main() {


FILE *ts_file = NULL;
ts_file = fopen64("/home/ddd/Desktop/Assignment/Streams/ddd.ts", "rb");

if (ts_file == NULL){
    cout << "No file detected on this path, try again" << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!
}

TS_Analyzer *ts_analyzer;
ts_analyzer->parse_file(ts_file);


cout << "Finished main" << endl;
return 0;
```

}

void TS_Analyzer::parse_file(FILE *ts_file){

```
cout << "Inside parser" << endl;

fseek(ts_file,0,SEEK_END);
long file_size = ftell(ts_file);
rewind (ts_file);

number_of_packets = file_size/PACKET_SIZE;
unsigned int current_header_add = 0;
unsigned int i=0;


for (unsigned int j=1; i<number_of_packets; j++)
{
    i++;
    unsigned char TS_raw_header[4];

    cout  << "current position " << int(current_header_add) << endl;

    current_header_add = ftell(ts_file);

    fread(&TS_raw_header, sizeof(TS_raw_header), 1, ts_file);

    Packet current_packet;

    current_packet.sync_byte = TS_raw_header[0];
    current_packet.transport_error_indicator = (TS_raw_header[1] & 0x80) >> 7;
    current_packet.payload_start_indicator = (TS_raw_header[1] & 0x40) >> 6;
    current_packet.transport_priority = (TS_raw_header[1] & 0x20) >> 5;
    current_packet.PID = ((TS_raw_header[1] & 31) << 8) | TS_raw_header[2];
    current_packet.transport_scrambling_control = (TS_raw_header[3] & 0xC0);
    current_packet.adaption_field_control = (TS_raw_header[3] & 0x30) >> 4;
    current_packet.continuity_counter = (TS_raw_header[3] & 0xF);


    stream_packets.push_back(current_packet);

    //cout  << hex << int(current_packet.PID) << endl;
    //cout  << dec << "continuity counter " << int(current_packet.continuity_counter) << endl;
    cout  << " i " << int(i) << endl;

    fseek(ts_file, 184, SEEK_CUR);
 }
cout  << "@@" << endl;
cout << stream_packets.size() << endl;
```

}

class TS_Analyzer: public Analyzer {

public:
    TS_Analyzer();
    ~TS_Analyzer();

```
struct Packet {
    unsigned char sync_byte;
    unsigned char transport_error_indicator;
    unsigned char payload_start_indicator;
    unsigned char transport_priority;
    unsigned int PID;
    unsigned char transport_scrambling_control;
    unsigned char adaption_field_control;
    unsigned char continuity_counter;
};

std::vector<Packet>stream_packets;

int number_of_packets = 0;


void parse_file(FILE *);
```

};

Any ideas of why the vector push_back breaks the for loop and why i cannot get a correct vector size?

Comment: can we see the error?

Comment: it is not an error, it just stops on the 163rd loop. When i put the loop lets say until 111, then the loop finishes and if i print the size of the vector i get that 11727604084342.

Comment: What is the PACKET_SIZE? It is nowhere defined. What the Analyzer class does? Also nowhere defined. fopen64() used ... can it be bigger than 2GB file? On such case it is possible that long can't contain its length on target platform. What various other functions (fseek fread etc.) return is systematically ignored, so it won't pass review as real production code anyway. Also uninitialized object used what JVApen already answered, most compilers complain of it.

Comment: Packet size is defined as 188,sorry i did not include that code.The Analyzer is just a base class that does nothing yet. Why wont that work for a file bigger than 2gb? I will check the uninitialized object and get back to you asap.

Comment: Use it instead of  magic numbers for example PACKET_SIZE-sizeof(TS_raw_header) instead of  184. It is likely not the problem but makes it easier to follow your code.

Comment: ok , i will make that change. can you please also explain why it will not work for files over 2gb ? what should i change? i have different files that i should test, with different sizes and one of them is over 2gb ... i haven't tried it yet though, but i would appreciate an explanation. thank you

Comment: @jmfel I guess they are assuming a limitation of 32bit. With 32bit, you can address 4GB of data (give or take), so with a signed 32 bit integer that is 2GB in every direction. So most likely the assumption is that the underlying structure is using 32 bit integers for addressing in the file. PS: Why are you still using FILE*, when you could be using std::fstream?

Comment: what could i change in order to make it work for larger files? should i use fstream instead? is there a huge difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I put this code through the clang compiler, I get an error on following code:

```
TS_Analyzer *ts_analyzer;
ts_analyzer->parse_file(ts_file);

>> variable 'ts_analyzer' is uninitialized when used here
```

I guess you are encountering undefined behavior: As ts_analyzer as ptr is any random value, the data in its members is also very random.

I'm actually surprised that this code runs at all without crashing, though you can always be lucky.

If you like to fix this, try avoiding pointers by creating the object at the stack:

```
TS_Analyzer ts_analyzer;
ts_analyzer.parse_file(ts_file);
```

or if you really need allocated memory, at least fill in the pointer:

```
auto ts_analyzer = std::make_unique<TS_Analyzer>();
ts_analyzer->parse_file(ts_file);
```

Comment: Yes it is most likely cause since the std::vector<Packet>stream_packets; is in some random memory location uninitialized and so can easily output 11727604084342 as its size.

Comment: I will check the uninitialized object asap, i am not at the pc at the moment, and i will get back to you.

Comment: Ok, i changed from a pointer to an object at the stack and now it works great. the loop finishes and the vector size is ok. thanks a lot !